# intl extension: installing php_intl in Moodle

Tags: php, wampserver

I have WAMPSERVER 3.0.6 64 bit. 
I have updated PHP version 5.6.25 from 7.0.10.
I have installed updated version of Moodle 3.4 and have tried to run but getting the issue is following -
Intl extension is required to improve internationalization support, such as locale aware sorting and international domain names.

For resolving this issue I have tried so many tips but could not resolve this issue.

Comment: it should be available as a pre-packaged extension of wamp ... look for it in the modules section to enable it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Even after doing the steps in [moodle doc](https://docs.moodle.org/34/en/admin/environment/php_extension/intl)
if it is not working, Try to do this.
Change the directory to php folder(server/PHP/) and type the this command

```
deplister.exe ext\php_intl.dll
```

It list down all the .dll files in moodle.
If there is any file 'Notfound', Download missing dlls from  : [dllfiles.com](https://www.dllfiles.com/download/18ed48cb7eb16a041f35ca80de8ae804/msvcp140.dll.htm?c=T01iZFhIYmRVREo1eFFzKzMxZXdkQT09)

For 64-Bit windows you have to download 32-Bit file + 64-Bit file

> Copy msvcp140.dll (32-bit file) into C:/Windows/SYSWOW64
>
> Copy msvcp140.dll (64-bit file) into C:/Windows/System32

Check if it is using deplister.exe ext\php_intl.dll command.

Refresh and see the environment by Site Administration->Server -> Environment

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be a late answer. Anyways, if someone stll looking for information, these steps could help:

- open PHP.ini in edit mode using notepad or whatever editor
- add:
  extension= php_intl.dll
- Then add:

  [intl]

  intl.default_locale = en_utf8

  intl.error_level = E_WARNING
- You may need to restart the webserver
- It will work fine

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I realized I did not have all the necessary .dll files. To check missing files go to xampp/php in your cmd terminal and type `deplister.dll ext\php_intl.dll`
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ9PJ.png)
You will see list of all both available and missing files marked as `Ok or Notfound`
then download the files from here https://www.dll-files.com/search/?q=string. Extract the files and place the .dll file at windows/system32. Remember this requires administrative privileges.